Free Windows PDF editor which support text redacting
I would like a free PDF editor for Windows 11 which supports:

text redaction (i.e., permanent removal, not just covering it with a black box). This is the same as the Redact feature of Apple Preview
multiple PDF merging
(nice to have, but not mandatory) digital signing

Do you have any suggestions?
PS just for clarity, this must be an offline PDF editor. I thought this was implied by the fact that I specified "for Windows 11", but maybe better to be safe than sorry :-)
